# leetcode: how can merge sort solve sum of minimum number in all continued substrings

Tags: python-3.x

I a new student of python and try to use merge sort to solve the question. I don't know what's wrong with the code.
The question is about finding the sum of minimum number in all continued substrings in a list, like [1,2,3] will output 10 because the minimum number in [1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,2,3] is 1,2,3,1,2,1 which has a sum of 10
The code is:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum_of_nums = 0
    def sumSubarrayMins(self, arr: list[int]) -> int:
        if len(arr) > 0:
            smallest = arr.index(min(arr))
            left = arr[:smallest]
            right = arr[smallest+1:]
            self.sumSubarrayMins(left)
            self.sumSubarrayMins(right)
            self.sum_of_nums += (len(left)+1)*(len(right)+1)*arr[smallest]
        return self.sum_of_nums
```

and the list given is:

```
[29959,29867,29822,29704,29676,29650,29577,29488,29286,29255,29232,29207,29071,29034,28925,28849,28731,28693,28624,28606,28591,28397,28357,28308,28295,28210,28119,28090,28004,27903,27845,27830,27777,27736,27640,27540,27506,27428,27341,27308,27182,27152,27122,27029,26928,26872,26796,26765,26663,26597,26580,26530,26498,26475,26436,26406,26382,26312,26213,26134,26088,26025,25943,25912,25875,25845,25810,25702,25638,25614,25531,25524,25488,25470,25444,25402,25283,25262,25121,24988,24958,24886,24769,24697,24635,24595,24490,24456,24453,24346,24313,24248,24200,24148,24107,24052,24044,24021,23970,23908,23897,23835,23752,23741,23714,23661,23596,23545,23509,23470,23439,23409,23350,23215,23166,23155,23100,23024,22923,22825,22793,22627,22613,22536,22450,22383,22312,22268,22205,22175,22136,22028,21971,21900,21824,21769,21726,21583,21546,21513,21494,21428,21327,21264,21254,21174,21140,21112,21000,20921,20902,20830,20817,20783,20735,20657,20616,20573,20485,20378,20363,20305,20259,20210,20114,20002,19846,19785,19747,19667,19645,19622,19610,19580,19542,19516,19454,19392,19310,19277,19194,19131,19090,19004,18883,18845,18791,18781,18668,18591,18518,18475,18368,18331,18310,18287,18217,18114,18092,18048,17990,17964,17912,17836,17740,17704,17630,17613,17573,17428,17356,17341,17300,17260,17180,17174,17126,17071,17041,16866,16850,16828,16672,16618,16577,16499,16407,16357,16318,16293,16202,16150,16075,16041,15948,15921,15844,15843,15785,15764,15668,15626,15579,15473,15387,15255,15190,15139,15062,14996,14954,14918,14907,14902,14867,14851,14817,14799,14751,14720,14536,14506,14474,14353,14303,14280,14185,14107,14012,13932,13858,13781,13585,13563,13533,13451,13412,13362,13249,13208,13181,13064,13037,12961,12926,12892,12786,12731,12611,12573,12506,12502,12496,12470,12443,12370,12262,12182,12153,12069,12000,11847,11806,11781,11708,11687,11593,11550,11445,11372,11329,11308,11291,11268,11241,11191,11027,10982,10879,10862,10776,10695,10603,10502,10464,10350,10338,10305,10273,10176,10124,10094,10038,9953,9935,9812,9786,9743,9728,9508,9472,9383,9349,9236,9215,9130,9124,9042,9008,8988,8901,8833,8809,8780,8716,8580,8462,8334,8321,8305,8280,8257,8246,8137,8077,8043,8016,7984,7955,7927,7906,7746,7663,7653,7572,7542,7530,7489,7420,7390,7361,7337,7245,7210,7188,7175,7096,6898,6846,6745,6675,6569,6478,6427,6363,6284,6260,6243,6206,6154,6135,6078,6061,6017,5995,5917,5863,5836,5793,5763,5743,5678,5572,5532,5459,5384,5341,5299,5251,5231,4995,4933,4861,4740,4672,4625,4496,4445,4361,4282,4215,4135,4097,4028,3917,3862,3711,3553,3498,3410,3388,3384,3288,3279,3244,3221,3181,3171,3150,3060,3035,2975,2965,2834,2760,2637,2584,2533,2440,2383,2311,2285,2255,2211,2192,2121,2054,2010,1964,1850,1724,1642,1577,1411,1409,1332,1296,1265,1256,1220,1195,937,903,880,811,739,720,650,609,547,533,459,434,384,279,231,163,102,78,30,5,52,100,155,217,277,328,389,446,473,546,583,649,702,734,768,857,882,912,1043,1219,1243,1258,1290,1325,1359,1409,1567,1642,1679,1726,1873,1965,2017,2088,2172,2204,2226,2273,2288,2316,2434,2522,2558,2622,2678,2790,2933,2965,3025,3037,3071,3167,3180,3194,3233,3269,3282,3383,3387,3401,3465,3528,3595,3801,3910,4020,4078,4128,4213,4271,4295,4420,4472,4612,4663,4739,4845,4891,4980,5109,5241,5284,5335,5379,5388,5478,5546,5639,5705,5751,5766,5803,5855,5879,5975,6000,6024,6070,6093,6137,6156,6212,6256,6276,6304,6421,6441,6537,6614,6743,6844,6893,7087,7169,7183,7200,7237,7262,7352,7376,7398,7441,7491,7541,7564,7602,7656,7707,7814,7924,7940,7958,8014,8036,8048,8132,8141,8250,8279,8288,8321,8331,8374,8515,8655,8723,8807,8825,8878,8953,8990,9011,9077,9128,9172,9219,9276,9383,9420,9499,9535,9736,9744,9801,9900,9951,10038,10093,10119,10147,10265,10301,10314,10340,10456,10499,10564,10622,10767,10802,10876,10882,10997,11063,11217,11243,11276,11299,11314,11365,11407,11456,11587,11627,11705,11751,11792,11831,11901,12012,12118,12180,12240,12296,12385,12469,12473,12497,12503,12537,12578,12723,12778,12858,12901,12936,13020,13048,13136,13195,13232,13325,13377,13424,13493,13547,13564,13724,13856,13911,13938,14075,14151,14234,14300,14353,14395,14499,14507,14705,14724,14796,14802,14823,14858,14882,14905,14914,14936,14962,15049,15114,15161,15237,15272,15399,15565,15587,15666,15749,15778,15830,15843,15864,15928,16039,16075,16141,16163,16246,16315,16333,16389,16415,16526,16601,16650,16798,16845,16861,16991,17046,17090,17140,17178,17186,17292,17305,17343,17419,17456,17610,17617,17693,17728,17783,17909,17918,17970,18032,18083,18104,18114,18223,18296,18330,18363,18428,18496,18578,18660,18733,18782,18792,18861,18929,19069,19127,19184,19269,19279,19355,19394,19494,19539,19559,19599,19612,19643,19666,19745,19760,19815,19864,20012,20141,20231,20270,20330,20370,20380,20500,20595,20617,20690,20751,20811,20824,20843,20910,20925,21044,21126,21165,21198,21260,21280,21343,21467,21505,21531,21564,21640,21755,21817,21885,21929,22010,22103,22159,22196,22229,22270,22368,22414,22515,22570,22615,22630,22806,22864,22951,23030,23107,23155,23191,23226,23399,23438,23464,23487,23524,23559,23634,23667,23719,23747,23764,23869,23901,23936,24012,24022,24045,24074,24141,24185,24204,24272,24327,24452,24455,24490,24560,24615,24641,24734,24815,24890,24963,25025,25242,25282,25283,25414,25446,25475,25489,25527,25586,25636,25640,25771,25844,25848,25883,25923,26005,26048,26106,26157,26312,26359,26395,26429,26465,26491,26513,26558,26584,26601,26667,26770,26864,26900,26996,27118,27129,27176,27272,27313,27389,27478,27517,27580,27700,27761,27811,27844,27848,27967,28051,28108,28176,28264,28302,28332,28380,28525,28591,28617,28681,28727,28744,28874,28994,29047,29123,29221,29239,29274,29347,29493,29596,29668,29694,29717,29847,29871]
```

the output should be 508796209
but my output is 2508796223
What's wrong with the code?

I tried to found solution using merge sort in keys, but the key given is mostly Single stack

Answer (score 0):

I believe your solution should look something like this:

For loop:

```
my_sublists = [[1],[2,3],[4],[5,6,7],[8],[9]]

    
    min_numbers = []
    for i in my_sublists:
      min_numbers.append(min(i))
    
    sum(min_numbers) 
    
    29
```

List comprehension:

```
sum([min(i) for i in my_sublists])

29
```

Comment: The code find the smallest number of each list and split the list into 1 or 2 lists. Like [2,1,7,5]will be split into [2] and [7,5], sum_of_nums adds 1(smallest number) * 2(times of right list appear) * 3(right list can be) because 1 appears in right list:[1] [1,7] [1,7,5] right list can appear another time when there is number at left: [2,1] [2,1,7] [2,1,7,5] as the smallest